# How do you store cell phone numbers in a database?

Tags: sms, phone-number

With the age of text messages and things like that, what's a good way to store phone numbers in a database?

In the USA, text messages are handled by phone numbers but in other countries I hear they use email addresses so I guess there needs to be a way to differentiate between countries that use cell phone numbers as their address.

Addition:
For example, people in the USA might use 432-342-3333 or 1-432-342-3333 while in the UK they might use +44 800 400000 or they might even leave out the 44.  The 44 and the 1 makes a difference when automatically sending out SMS.  However, checking the phone number for each country can get tedious.  In this case, would you split the country code or would you merge it into a single column and deal it with it there?

Comment: Are you trying to store phone numbers?  Or messaging addresses?  The question title seems straightforward but then you talk about txt delivery via e-mail.  What is the actual question?

Answer (score 29):

I would primarily use a text field, or a series of text fields, even if you are using a numerical phone number for the following reasons.

1. Phone numbers have a great range of values, including extension numbers which may result in numerical columns losing precision.
2. Losing precision in a phone number is rather bad.
3. There is no logical reason to want to perform math ( addition/multiplication ) on a phone number.

Additionally, you may want to specify how you are using this data. If you are planning an automated messaging service, you're going to need a series of relaying agents to broadcast via, so you may as well add an identifier that pertains to the relay the information pertains to. Then all you have to worry about is that the relaying agent can understand the content in the text fields.

Comment: While I would still store as a string, you could eliminate 1&2 (which is really just 1 point) with a fixed point number.

Comment: @umassthrower unless you're using Excel and working with csv files. But if you're doing that, the solution to that problem is "stop using excel at all".

Comment: Just a notable comment I saw in my review queue on this post:

> It should be noted however that performing any aggregated functions i.e. SUM of the phone numbers stored in the database, is MUCH slower on a CHAR field than INTEGER. Because of this it is highly recommended to include an identity column you can use to count with for reporting.)

Thanks.

Comment: ... for all those apps where the sum of a column of telephone numbers has meaning

Comment: A phone number serves the sale purpose as a UID.  There are few if any reasons to use mathematical aggregates on them.  The only reason we even think to do something like that is because numbers are digits.  We could just as easily have made telephones with letters on them and given people letter based phone addresses.  This would have lead to a system not too disimillar to the domain name system of the WWW.  I don't typically consider the impact of mathematical aggregates when I store https://www.foo.com/bar.html as a varchar, do you?

Comment: I agree @umassthrower, theres little reason to do math on phone numbers, just I saw the comment the user had attempted to insert via edit, and I copy-pasted it as a comment instead of an edit so their opinion could be seen ( even if I happen to disagree with the comment ).

Answer (score 15):

Generally as text, you don't need all the fancy formatting, unless you need it to parse numbers from different countries that you can't distinguish otherwise.  You can always add the formatting later on.

Not as a number!!! Leading zeros may be problematic.

Comment: Definitely. The stripping of leading zeros for IntegerField has bit me sorely before.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if you have read these two questions, but they might help you a little.

- [Phone Number Columns in a Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290597/phone-number-columns-in-a-database)
- [Is there a standard for storing normalized phone numbers in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41925/is-there-a-standard-for-storing-normalized-phone-numbers-in-a-database)

Perhaps it would be wise to store the type of number (landline, cell, fax) and/or the messages that can be received on it (voice, text, email). Note that in the US, it is also possible to send text messages to a phone via email, but I believe that is dependent on the carrier.