# Error converting expression to data type int in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a table with 5 columns, and now I am trying to add new values into the table by using `insert into` method manually, but I'm getting an error even though all the values are of the same datatype as that of the given one.

I even tried to delete the entire table and create a new one and re add the columns again but still facing the same problem. I am able to add one column, that's it unable to add any others.

The following screenshot shows the structure of the table

[image]

and these are the values I'm trying to add:

```
insert into customers 
values (2, 'john', 'mexico', 87564, 6573892841),
       (3, 'thomas', 'brazil', 23897, 8734521897),
       (4, 'tim', 'dublin', 432987, 4328795478),
       (5, 'robert', 'centralccity', 83006, 1357986420),
       (6, 'rodeys', 'ireland', 601356, 8743561289),
       (7, 'barry', 'london', 101626, 9765423678),
       (8, 'cisco', 'manchester', 87235, 8743561288),
       (9, 'barry', 'london', 101636, 8712345288),
       (10, 'amy', 'manchester', 87235, 8743165288),
       (11, 'catline', 'singapore', 10101, 65436783),
       (12, 'guru', 'chennai', 600018, 7402367111)
```

Comment: Alter `Phone` column as `varchar (12)`

Comment: Hint: Storing phone as number is simply wrong. You are not going to perform arithmetic operations on that column plus leading zeros are lost. [How do you store cell phone numbers in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314686/how-do-you-store-cell-phone-numbers-in-a-database)

Comment: Those are **columns** of a table (not "elements" ....)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is 2 fold, the first is that you have values like `8712345288`, which are too large for an `int`. The largest number an int can store is 2,147,483,647; so your value is roughly 4 times too large.

The second problem, however, is that you are storing a phone number as a numerical data type. This is actually a really bad idea. Phone numbers can have leading zeros, formatting requirements, country codes, extensions, all of which a numerical data type like `int` won't be able to store.

Store your phone numbers as a `varchar`, by changing your column's definition:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.customers ALTER COLUMN Phone varchar(20);
```

Then insert your data again and it'll be fine.

Comment: yes i did change it to varchar and it is working now TQ

Answer (score 3):

Some of those phone numbers are to large to fit in a `int`, use `bigint` instead

Comment: Storing phone numbers as int/bigint/decimal is antipattern(i.e. leading zeros, + sign for country)

Comment: @joakim danielcon yes i did change it to varchar and it is working now TQ

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I was looking at the data type not the business logic. Deciding the correct data type for a specific use case is beyond the scope of this question. There is no mentioning of supporting country or area codes etc in the question

Comment: @JoakimDanielson `"Deciding the correct data type for a specific use case is beyond the scope of this question."` It is your call. I just point out the solving question without context would lead to issues in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your are trying to store value which is more than the limit of an integer. The maximum value of integer in positive is `2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)` but your are trying to insert value `6573892841` which is more than the max limit.

You can convert that type to `varchar` and then it will work as shown below.

```
create table #customers (Id int,
name varchar(10),
city varchar(50),
pincode int,
phone varchar(50))

insert into #customers values (2,'john','mexico',87564,6573892841)
,(3,'thomas','brazil',23897,8734521897)
,(4,'tim','dublin',432987,4328795478)
,(5,'robert','centralccity',83006,1357986420)
,(6,'rodeys','ireland',601356,8743561289)
,(7,'barry','london',101626,9765423678) 
,(8,'cisco','manchester',87235,8743561288)
,(9,'barry','london',101636,8712345288) 
,(10,'amy','manchester',87235,8743165288)
,(11,'catline','singapore',10101,65436783) 
 ,(12,'guru','chennai',600018,7402367111)
```

[**SQL Server Datatype Value Range**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: *"You can also use `bigint` inplace of `int`."* That is actually a bad idea for the reasons I gave in my answer. Stick to the `varchar` :)

Comment: @surajkuamr yes i did change it to varchar and it is working now TQ