# Mysql Datatype for US Zip (Postal Codes)

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design, data-modeling, zipcode

I am writing a web application, that is US specific, so the format that other countries use for postal codes are not important. I have a list of us zip codes that i am trying to load into a database table that includes the

- 5 digit us zip code
- latitude
- longitude
- usps classification code
- state code
- city

the zip code is the primary key as it is what i will be querying against. i started using a medium int 5 but that truncates the zip codes that have leading zeros.

i considered using a char5 but am concerned about the performance hit of indexing against a char variable.

so my question is what is the best mysql datatype to store zip codes as?

Note: i have seen it in several other questions related to zip codes. I am only interested in US 5 digit zip codes. So there is no need to take other countries postal code formats into consideration.

Comment: What's the value add in keeping the leading zeros?  So long as you display the leading zeroes (.PadLeft), I would keep your database optimized as far as possible.

Comment: The zeroes are important data in a zip code. Zip codes are *not* integers, even if they're made up entirely of numbers.

Comment: thats a fair point. i did a few test cases querying for 00210 etc and it returned the proper record. i guess it is more of a gut feeling about concerns for data integrity.

Comment: What about the newer Zip+4 codes? Ex: 91210-3889

Comment: @ceejayoz: So long as he displays zip codes with 5 digits, when will this ever pose a problem?  In case the US expands the zip code system and integrates characters?

Comment: It poses a problem in having to remember to zero-pad it every time. It presents a problem in sorting. Ultimately, there are much better data types like `char(5)` to store this data with.

Comment: @rlb.usa as far as i know the zip+4 format only provides a more specific location fix within that zip code, and being that i dont have that precise of dataset, and the fact that the precision of the current zip meets my requirements i am not worried about it.

Comment: @ceejayoz, sorting a numeric always works the same as a zero padded number stored in a char, or am I missing something?

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a MySQL zipcode radius database that my client can purchase in order to do radial/locus searches?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

char(5) is the correct way to go.  String indexing is quite fast, particularly when it is such a small data set.

You are correct in that you should never use an integer for a zip code, since it isn't truly numeric data.

Edit to add:
Check out this for good reasons why you don't use numbers for non-numerically important data:
[Is it a good idea to use an integer column for storing US ZIP codes in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893454/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-an-integer-column-for-storing-us-zip-codes-in-a-database)

Comment: Erich:  Why not an integer?  I would think that storing as an integer would help with type checking, you can add leading zeroes in the client, a character can be a non-digit ... Just wondering what point I'm missing.

Comment: The data set could be millions. Most likely there will be other addresses in the system where a zip is stored, and they should all be the same type

Comment: Zip Codes are not numeric data.  Numeric data is data in which it makes sense to do mathematical operations on, which you would never do with a Zip Code.  Otherwise, you are unfairly limiting your dataset.

As far as the data set size, if the Zip code is truly the PK, there are only 99,999 values, a very small dataset relatively.

Comment: if you have 10 million customers with zip codes that is a big dataset

Comment: KM, 50 megabytes is not a big data set.  An index with 10 million keys in it is relatively small in today's data management.

Comment: John: Integer should not be used, because the zipcode "00501" will be stored as "501" which may create problems.

Answer (score 2):

go with your medium INT(5) ZEROFILL, it should add the leading zeros for you.  No need to impact the index and performance on a formatting issue.

Comment: as a char 5 it took .0007 seconds as medint5 zerofill it took .0006 seconds. i think both are valid solutions, but i think i am going to go with char5 and take the slight performance hit for a little more peace of mind on the data integrity front.

Answer (score 1):

If he makes it Char(6), then he can handle Canadian postal codes as well.

When you consider that there is a maximum of 100,000 5-digit Zip Code and how little space it would take up even if you made the entire table memory-resident, there's no reason not to.

Comment: I saw that from the original post.  I just figured I'd mention it in case anyone else looked at this question in the future looking for advice but had a situation where foreign postal codes MIGHT make a difference.  My main point was that, in the age of gigabyte memory sticks, a zip code table is pretty small.  (I dealt with these when memory was measured in KILObytes)