# MySQL CSV import not inserting 0's

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a `.txt` file that is in CSV format using phpmyadmin. It is a ZipCode database of the United States. When I select the import option and then load the file everything gets inserted successfully except for the ZipCodes that start with a `0` It will not add the `0`'s so for example ZipCode `00601` gets added as `601`, `01234` gets added as `1234`. Has anyone experienced this before or know a way to prevent this? I have included a snippet of the `.txt` file below.

Snippet:

```
"00601","+18.165273","-066.722583","ADJUNTAS","PR","ADJUNTAS","STANDARD"
"00602","+18.393103","-067.180953","AGUADA","PR","AGUADA","STANDARD"
"00603","+18.455913","-067.145780","AGUADILLA","PR","AGUADILLA","STANDARD"
"00604","+18.493520","-067.135883","AGUADILLA","PR","AGUADILLA","STANDARD"
```

Comment: what is the datatype of the ZipCode column in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have the ZipCode data type as Integer and that is why the lead zeroes are omitted. Change the ZipCode data type to char(5) as answered here: 
[Mysql Datatype for US Zip (Postal Codes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493926/mysql-datatype-for-us-zip-postal-codes)