# PHP: How do I get my IF statement to work with PDO select?

Tags: php, pdo

I want my below PDO select to work with the bottom two IF statements?
The first IF I just want to make sure there is no error.
The second IF I want to check how many rows it returns. I know that this `number of rows == 0` will not work.
Is there a way to do that?

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=zs', 'zs', 'rlkj08sfSsdf');
    $conn ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM zip WHERE zip_code =:zip1");
$stmt->bindValue(':zip1', $_POST[zipcode], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


if($rows = "") {
    echo "<p><strong>There was a database error attempting to retrieve your ZIP Code.</strong></p>\n";
}
if(number of rows == 0) {
    echo "<p><strong>No database match for provided ZIP Code.</strong> Please enter a new ZIP Code.</p>\n"; 
}
```

Comment: `if($rows = "") {` This is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: `fetchAll()` returns an array. You can use `empty()` or `count()` to test if if has anything in it.

Comment: Dont consider zip codes `int`s, you will have issues with leading zeros. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893454/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-an-integer-column-for-storing-us-zip-codes-in-a-databas

Comment: You should NEVER EVER use a $_POST variable in SELECT without proper filtering - this is calling for SQL injection!

Comment: @Zac67 he's using prepared statements. Your comment is absolutely false.

Comment: @Zac67 The OP is not doing that.. This is the correct implementation.

Comment: Just a side note - I upvoted this, not because it's an excellent question, but because it's really one of rare PDO related questions where the OP correctly sets PDO in exception mode, uses `bindValue` instead of `bindParam` and even does explicit type binding. It's refreshing to see that at least some people read the manual right.

Comment: @N.B. But he forgot quotes around the array index :)

Comment: `$_POST[zipcode]` should be `$_POST['zipcode']`

Comment: @Barmar he did, and I did correct that in the answer I posted. Still, it's much better use of PDO than most of php + mysql related questions around here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're interested only in whether there are records containing a particular value. It makes no sense to select *everything* and count the records in PHP. It's a waste of resources. Imagine what happens if there's a million records.

Solution you're after is to simply ask your database about the `COUNT` of rows containing a particular value. Your code should be quite simple:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM zip WHERE zip_code = :zip");
$stmt->bindValue(':zip', $_POST['zipcode'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();

$count = (int)$stmt->fetchColumn();

if($count)
{
    echo "Success";
}
else
{
    echo "Bummer";
}
```

Notes:

- if successful, the above query will always return 1 row with 1 column, named `num_rows` which will be `0` for no matching records or an integer larger than `0` if there are records. If you use MySQL native driver with PHP, PHP will correctly represent this value as integer internally. I deliberately put typecasting in, you can remove it (the `(int)` part) if you have MySQL ND.
- if something goes wrong during query execution, an exception will be thrown. The snippet doesn't cover that. You correctly set PDO in exception mode, and along with using `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`, this implies you did your research right and you're using PDO correctly which means that error handling should be implemented easily by you in this particular case.