# EXCEL formula with the formatted value insted of real value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel file with a zip codes and I need get the first 2 numbers
=LEFT(G2;2);

for this postal codes like **11008** it works, I get **11**, but if a postal code has as value **01008** this doesn't works because the unformatted (Real Value) value is **1008**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could turn the zip code first into text using `TEXT`:

```
=LEFT(TEXT(G2;"00000");2)
```

`1008` becomes `01008` first, and then you get `01` from the `LEFT` function.

Comment: I had to use `=LEFT(TEXT(G2,"00000"),2)` for it to work.

Comment: @SethB This is because of language and region settings. In some countries, you'd use `;`, otherwise, `,`.

Answer (score 2):

Your ZIP code column should really be formatted as Text.  Even though the ZIP code happens to be represented with numerals, it's not really a number per se.

- You don't do math with it;
- it could just as easily be represented with letters (and is in some countries);
- leading zeros are important.

Same thing with, say, phone numbers.

Here's some relevant questions:

- [Is it a good idea to use an integer column for storing US ZIP codes in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893454/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-an-integer-column-for-storing-us-zip-codes-in-a-databas)
- [Phone Number Columns in a Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290597/phone-number-columns-in-a-database)